# How To Create Users Who Are Chrooted At A Directory

Tags: linux, permissions, chroot

Is it possible to have users on linux, who's home directory is still the default `/home/joe` but when they login via ssh/sftp, they are chroot at `/apps/web/`?

Basically I wanted to keep all users files .bashrc, .bash_profile, .ssh in their home `/home/joe` directory, but they should only have access to `/apps/web` and further when they login via ssh/sftp.

I am on CentOS 5.6 x86.

**Update**

I put the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but when I try and sftp in with a user in the group deploy it is not working.

```
Match Group deploy
        ChrootDirectory /apps/web
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got the sftp working with:

```
Match Group deploy
        ChrootDirectory /apps/web
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

And the permissions of /apps/web need to be user and group owned by root.

Comment: what are your directory permissions on /apps/web? (ls -la)